# Is there an R function for construct a boxplot including 2 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I wanted to construct a boxplot with the following two variables. I want the state to be x-axis and the ratio to be y-axis and the final plot is a combination of boxplots of each state. The real data is much larger.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
State   Ratio
WA  100.00%
TX  66.67%
TX  100.00%
CA  0.00%
CO  80.00%
IN  50.00%
MI  0.00%
TX  40.00%
OH  0.00%
UT  0.00%
CA  0.00%
AZ  0.00%
TX  0.00%
GA  0.00%
NY  25.00%
DC  20.00%
NY  85.71%
CA  0.00%
TN  0.00%
CA  40.00%
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

When I used

```
boxplot(ratio~State, data = df)
```

it returns

```
adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

I have checked about this error and I know this occurs because both my state and ratio are factor classes. However, if I convert it into integer, it will lose some information. Hope for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is with the **"%"** in the Ratio variable. You need to transform the variable into a number.

```
df$Ratio <- gsub("%","", df$Ratio)
df$Ratio <- as.numeric(df$Ratio)

boxplot(Ratio~State, data = df)

#ggplot2 is an option:

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = State, y = Ratio))
```

Comment: I am glad it helped you!

Comment: ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = State, y = Ratio)) + ggtitle("Fancy Name")

Comment: Thanks! Actually I figured it out myself! Anyway, thank you!